# win32 PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR color bit count and color bit shift

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

So in creating a context for openGL using win32 I have found this generic pixel format descriptor that everyone seems to be referencing. However after looking at the documentation I have found that the documentation for the color bits and color bit shifts does not describe how to actually format the buffer, and I cannot find any more information online.

Is there some place I can get more information on the color bit count and color bit shifts function, or have a description of how they work.

```
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd =
{
    sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
    1,
    PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,    // Flags
    PFD_TYPE_RGBA,        // The kind of framebuffer. RGBA or palette.
    32,                   // Colordepth of the framebuffer.
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    24,                   // Number of bits for the depthbuffer
    8,                    // Number of bits for the stencilbuffer
    0,                    // Number of Aux buffers in the framebuffer.
    PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
    0,
    0, 0, 0
};
```

Comment: Scroll down here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-choosepixelformat and see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685887/opengl-in-windows/69840303#69840303

Comment: The pixelformat structure must be passed to the ChoosePixelFormat() function which returns an index to a suitable pixelformat structure for the hdc. Then you use the SetPixelFormat() function to set this pixel format.

Comment: If you use OpenGL you don't need a buffer. You call wglMakeCurrent() and makes the OpenGL context draw onto the back buffer of the HDC for the Window. Then, when you call OpenGL functions, it will draw onto the back buffer that you swap with the front buffer by calling SwapBuffer(dc).